# Is there away to perform probabilistic PCA using python and sci-kit learn.?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

Is there away to perform probabilistic PCA using python and sci-kit learn.? I am trying to perform ppca but I can't find a library that does it.

Answer (score 0):

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_pca_vs_fa_model_selection.html

Theres an example that kind of gets into it and I think will help you. It looks like you have to do your own scoring to get the exact probabilistic PCA implementation you're after for your data. Probably playing around with the results of an implementation similar to that will help you figure out your issues.